# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't use my Radeon HD 8670M, uses intel instead

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

After a lot of research, I stumbled upon a problem I cannot resolve. 
I am trying to make ubuntu use my dedicated Radeon graphics card (HD 8670M), but no matter what I try (and trust me, I did go over every single thread related to my problem here) Ubuntu doesn't want to use it. Which is a problem, because the integrated intel one doesn't support 3D acceleration. I have installed the open-source AMD driver already (xorg amd and mesa), but this doesn't solve my problem.

To add insult to injury when I run `lscpi | grep VGA` - only intel is listed. That being said - if I run `lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'` I get the following:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile] [1002:6660]
```

One more thing - when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following odd message:

```
  The following packages have been kept back:
  libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 linux-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-headers-lowlatency linux-image-generic
  linux-image-lowlatency linux-lowlatency ubuntu-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

Please advise on how to proceed.

Comment: answer to the last part: upgrades. Simply run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to upgrade the 15 remaining packages and `sudo apt autoremove` to do some cleaning

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. It didn't occur to me, as I did a dist upgrade just a few days ago (I haven't used my laptop for about one year).